# DocuSign REST API INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE sending envelope from template with application/json

Tags: google-apps-script, docusignapi, http-status-code-415

I am using Google Apps Script to make a URL request to https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/ACCOUNT-ID/envelopes (where ACCOUNT-ID is my proper numerical account ID.)

It's being sent with the code `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)`.

`params` is

```
{
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer "+jwt,
    ContentType: "application/json"
  },
  payload: payload
}
```

`jwt` is a token retrieved from the JWT auth flow at execution time, and `payload` is

```
{
  "accountId": accountID,
  "emailSubject": subject,
  "templateId": templateID,
  "templateRoles": [{
    "email": data['email'],
    "name": data['name'],
    "roleName": "Seller",
    "tabs": {
      "textTabs": [
        {"tabLabel": "Seller", "value": data['name']},
        ...
      ]
    }
  }],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Variables used here are defined as expected in a manner consistent with the [example given by DocuSign](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/templates#sending-from-a-template)

When I execute this, I get the following response with an HTTP 415.
`{"errorCode":"INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE","message":"Content Type specified is not supported."}`

I have tried removing the ContentType header, passing the payload as a string, and both at once, to no avail. I also tried providing the GUID instead of the numerical ID for accountID, but it came out the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content type should be specified as 
[`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) (with a `-`) inside `headers` object or as [`contentType`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app.html#fetch(String,Object)) inside `params` or `options` object. `payload` should also be `JSON.stringify`ied.